# Iterating thru Object properties produces different results in different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, for-loop

I am creating a very basic object in JavaScript and looping thru its properties, displaying property name:

```
var name = {
                'A': 'DataA',
                'B': 'DataB',
                'C': 'DataC',
                'D': 'DataD',
                'E': 'DataE'
            }

for (var propName in name) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += propName + '&nbsp;'
}
```

In IE and FireFox it produces expected result:

```
A B C D E
```

But in Chrome same code produces

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Any idea why? Does keyword `name` hold some significance in Chrome?

Comment: [Are you sure?](http://jsfiddle.net/cqvrF/)

Comment: JSFiddle for some reason doesn't show the effect, but when I open HTML page with code in browser directly - this happens

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to like it when you use it as a global (there's a name property on the window object). Just run it inside a function.

Comment: @zdyn That was it! Apparently `name` in Chrome is `[Object, Object]` this is where where these properties come from. Weird stuff. Running it with a private `name` variable works. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Will do, glad to help.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, your fiddle is wrapping the code in a function, that's why it doesn't break, see http://jsfiddle.net/cqvrF/2/ You have to choose the nowrap option...

Comment: @Juan Mendes: thanks, captain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome doesn't seem to like it when you use it as a global variable (there's also a name property on the window object). Just run it inside a function.

Answer (score -5):

try

```
for (var propName in name) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += (propName + '&nbsp;');
}
```

Comment: What do you think it would change (for *working* code)? Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence before you delete your answer :-)

Comment: The thing is, when I debug the page `propName` does show those numbers

Comment: I'm not going to delete that since it MAKES a difference

Comment: @Axel Amthor: please explain what difference it makes

Comment: @AxelAmthor -1 It does not make a difference

Comment: as you might have seen, browsers do not always tightly stick to the reference of JS, it depends. Even with IE and Chrome its more or  less a try and error whether things work or not. I've just tried to check the above with jsfiddle on IE - jsfiddle doesn't work in my IE 8 on XP :-/. "Reserved" words like "name" or "form" i.e. I only know from causing problems in IE, not in Chrome (yet). So I agree, it was a guess, but pointing me to the JS reference is somewhat offending. If all browsers would implement that properly, we would have 50% less questions over here.

Comment: Browsers implement operator precedence correctly. Browser incompatibility stems mainly from the DOM API, occasionally from the native API, and almost never from the basic language syntax, aside from a few edge cases here and there. If you're inclined to be offended by someone offering you helpful documentation, then don't post answers that have no basis in reality.